# What was the purpose of adding the safeTransferFrom method? What are the cases when the plain transferFrom fails silently?

Tags: erc-20, transfer, safemath

I was wondering what is the case when the plain transferFrom ERC20 method fails silently, i.e., just returning false.

Looking at the code, to me it looks like when the balance is insufficient or the allowence is the low, it'd just throw an error. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all ERC20 tokens follow the OpenZeppelin implementation that you linked. Some implementations of ERC20 tokens will not revert and will simply return `false` if the transaction failed. This could lead to unexpected behaviour if you expect a failed transfer to revert.

In ERC20 `safeTransferFrom` library implementations (e.g. [solmate](https://github.com/transmissions11/solmate/blob/main/src/utils/SafeTransferLib.sol#L31), [solady](https://github.com/Vectorized/solady/blob/main/src/utils/SafeTransferLib.sol#L178), and [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol#L44)) the helper method will ensure that the function reverts if `false` is returned from `transferFrom`.